# Extraneous input error when using "lexer rule actions" and "lexer commands"

Tags: antlr4

I'm seeing an "extraneous input" error with input "\aa a" and the following grammar:

Cool.g4

```
grammar Cool;
import Lex;

expr
   : STR_CONST # str_const
   ;
```

Lex.g4

```
lexer grammar Lex;

@lexer::members {
  public static boolean initial = true;
  public static boolean inString = false;
  public static boolean inStringEscape = false;
}

BEGINSTRING: '"' {initial}? {
  inString = true;
  initial = false;
  System.out.println("Entering string");
} -> more;

INSTRINGSTARTESCAPE: '\\' {inString && !inStringEscape}? {
  inStringEscape = true;
  System.out.println("The next character will be escaped!");
} -> more;

INSTRINGAFTERESCAPE: ~[\n] {inString && inStringEscape}? {
  inStringEscape = false;
  System.out.println("Escaped a character.");
} -> more;

INSTRINGOTHER: (~[\n\\"])+ {inString && !inStringEscape}? {
  System.out.println("Consumed some other characters in the string!");
} -> more;

STR_CONST: '"' {inString && !inStringEscape}? {
  inString = false;
  initial = true;
  System.out.println("Exiting string");
};

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

ID:  [a-z][_A-Za-z0-9]*;
```

Here's the output:

```
$ grun Cool expr -tree
"\aa a"
Entering string
The next character will be escaped!
Escaped a character.
Consumed some other characters in the string!
Exiting string
line 1:0 extraneous input '"\aa' expecting STR_CONST
(expr "\aa  a")
```

Interestingly, if I remove the ID rule, antlr parses the input fine. Here's the output when I remove the ID rule:

```
$ grun Cool expr -tree
"\aa a"
Entering string
The next character will be escaped!
Escaped a character.
Consumed some other characters in the string!
Exiting string
(expr "\aa a")
```

Any idea what might be going on? Why does antlr throw an error when ID is one of the Lexer rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the answer I received from @sharwell on [GitHub](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/2570).

"Your `ID` rule is unpredicated, so it matches `aa` following the `\` (`aa` is longer than the `a` matched by `INSTRINGAFTERESCAPE`, so it's preferred even though it's later in the grammar). If you add a `println` to `WS` and `ID` you'll see the strange behavior in the output."

Answer (score 0):

That's a surprisingly complex way to parse strings with escape sequences. Did you print the resulting tokens to see what your lexer produced?

I recommond a different (and much simpler) approach:

```
STR_CONST: '"' ('\\"' | .)*? '"';
```

Then in your semantic phase, when you post process your parse tree, examine the matched text to find escape sequences. Convert them to the real chars and print a good error message, when an invalid escape sequence was found (something you cannot do when trying to match escape sequences in the lexer).

Comment: Hi Mike. I solved the issue by using STR_CONST: '"' ( ESC | .)*? '"'; fragment ESC: '\\"' | '\\\\' ; But I still don't understand why antlr throws an error when ID is one of the Lexer rules. Is this expected behavior in antlr? Side note: You mentioned printing the resulting tokens. How do I do this? Is it different from the 'grun Cool expr -tree' command?

Comment: Can't tell off my head why the ID rule has that surprising effect. That would need to be debugged in detail. For printing the tokens: I never used `grun` so I cannot say if it allows to do that, but in code, with your generated lexer you can call `fill()` to parse all tokens and then iterate over them and print their text representation. That will show you what types the lexer found and if they are what you expected.